# Change Default Culture in AspNetBoilerplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

Even after reading this sources:

[Add a setting to get/set default language](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/692)

[Set language per user or per domain #272](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-forsaken/issues/272)

I could not set my application to start with a default language.

My languages are working fine. The user can choose what want after the page load. But the page must load as one culture other than default english.

I want my web.config stay with:

```xml
<system.web>
  <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this options, unsuccessfuly:

- Change **AppSettingProvider.cs** in **{template}.core**, to add a new
  **SettingDefinition**
- Added **Configuration.Localization.Languages** by hand in **{template}.Web** **{template}WebModule.PreInitialize()** method setting default true to **LanguageInfo**
- Overrided **SetCurrentCulture()** in Global.asax

After all, the solution was very simple.

Just change the setting into database table **AbpSettings** where Name column is "Abp.Localization.DefaultLanguageName" and UserId is null:

```sql
update AbpSettings 
   set Value = 'pt-BR' 
 where UserId is null 
   and rtrim(Name) like 'Abp.Localization.DefaultLanguageName';
```

Answer (score 1):

go to Seed Folder and DefaultSettingsCreator file and then change:

```
AddSettingIfNotExists(LocalizationSettingNames.DefaultLanguage, "pt-BR", tenantId);
```